# Sitecore Analytics Location has no data

Tags: xdb

I populated sample analytics data via jMeter in testing environment. I could see all sample data reports through Sitecore Analytics dashboard, but the Location data(graph) shows empty.

Even I populated sample data and could see the visit random generated IP addressees at MongoDB, do I have to purchase Sitecore IP Geolocation service to enable Location data view (graph)?

I have set `Analytics.ForwardedRequestHttpHeader` as `X-Forwarded-For`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, purchasing the Sitecore GeoIp and Device Detection will populate those areas out of the box. You can enable these in the AppCenter.

That being said, the `<commitSession>` pipeline has a processor called **UpdateGeoIpData** that could potentially be overriden to provide a 3rd party GeoIp lookup source.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some info to this answer. If you try and implement your own GeoIP lookup, you have to make sure country code are in the format of the countries in children the /sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Lookups/Countries item. The country code has to match 1:1.

The same thing has to happen for Region Codes. You can find the region codes in the dll Sirecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api in the namespace Sirecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Resources.RegionResources.resource. Again you have to make sure you are pushing into xDB the region code exactly as it is in the resource file above.

http://www.screencast.com/t/Pfrf4iyE